# PWA for Intranet

Tags: progressive-web-apps, local

I'm looking at making PWA applications for intranet use.  The trouble I'm having here is the TLS/SSL protocol.

I'd like to use modern UI tools (VueJS, PWA, Rest, Graph, etc) to build some internal apps at my company.  The problem I have, is that there is so much requirement build around SSL/TLS.  This isn't the most neccessary thing to have in an internal network, and I'd like to avoid wastefull calls to the internet.  Some of the clients I work with are even in remote areas where internet connections at all are problematic.

[image]

I'd like to avoid all the red arrows, but their required for things like service workers, etc.  Its odd, that doing something like rest, locally is so difficult.  Anyone know how to work around this?

Comment: What are you talking about? Your browser is __not__ calling the cert provider to verify the certificate.

Comment: Just deploy the required root cert to the user computers, normally no connection is required unless the user PC is outdated

Comment: @tkausl - I thought the point of ssl is that the client can verify the cert as trusted by comparing its digital signature to a trusted source?

Comment: The "trusted source" is installed on your computer though, no need to round trip to the certificate authority.

Comment: @Martheen- this turned out to be a compound problem.  There seems to be a significant amount of faffing around when trying to create a cert that Chrome and FireFox will accept locally.  Anyway, your answer is correct for the scope of the question.  If you post an answer I'll mark it correct.